# Time average from netCDF in 4 dimensions

Tags: r, environment-variables, netcdf4

i'm a master degree student in marine biology, and i'm new in the R world. I would really appreciate your help.

In short, I downloaded from the Copernicous repository a set of ocean environmental variables as netCDF files, which include as dimensions: 1)time (20 years split into monthly data), 2)depth (48 intervals to bottom), 3)latitude and 4) longitude of my study area. I should obtain a final raster file with the **average **of the netCDF variables (uo and vo currents) for all the years considered, keeping the intervals of the "depth" dimension (that's because after i will overlap these avarage values to a bathymetry considering the depth value).

Did you have any suggestion? many Thanks in advance

```
print(currents_nc)
2 variables (excluding dimension variables): short 
vo[longitude,latitude,depth,time]short uo [longitude,latitude,depth,time]   
4 dimensions:
time  Size:241
depth  Size:48  
latitude  Size:92
longitude  Size:111
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this perhaps? https://ropensci.org/blog/2019/11/05/tidync/ and also in the `stars` package: https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/read_ncdf.html

Comment: Thank you !for the next time .. how can I edit myself the script above in the correct format for the forum ? :)